# How do I calculate the year difference in my programm?

Tags: java, date, methods

I am writing a program where a user can enter date and let it print out. Aswell the program has a given date to calculate the year difference with a second entry. My current problem is, that when I call the calculation method everything seems to work out fine but unfortunately the output is always 0.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Dates{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Attributes
    static int Day;
    static int Month;
    static int Year;

    //Constructor
    Dates(int x, int y, int z){
        Day = 12;
        Month = 12;
        Year = 2019;
        if(Day > 31) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Wrong day! repeat entry: ");
                Day = scan.nextInt();
            }while (Day > 31);
        }
        if(Month > 12) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Wrong month! repeat entry: ");
                Month = scan.nextInt();
            }while(Month > 12); 
        }
        if(Year < 1800) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Year! repeat entry: ");
                Year = scan.nextInt();
            }while(Year < 1800);
        }
    }
//Calculates Year difference
public static int getYeardiff(int day, int month, int year) {
    System.out.println("Press <0>, if you want to know passed years between two dates. ");
    int difference = 0;
    int key = scan.nextInt();
    if(key == 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter a second date: ");
        Dates diffr = new Dates(Day, Month, Year);
        diffr.Day = scan.nextInt();
        diffr.Month = scan.nextInt();
        diffr.Year = scan. nextInt();
        if(diffr.Year <= Dates.Year) {
            difference = Dates.Year - diffr.Year;
            System.out.println(difference);
        }
    }
    return difference;
}
//Formats the date into a String.
public static String asString(int day, int month, int year) {
    String stringDay = "" + Day;
    String stringMonth = "" + Month;
    String stringYear = "" + Year;
    String stringDate = stringDay + "." + stringMonth+ "." + stringYear;
    System.out.println(stringDate);
    return stringDate;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter todays date!");
    Dates xmas = new Dates(Day, Month ,Year);
    xmas.Day = scan.nextInt();
    xmas.Month = scan.nextInt();
    xmas.Year = scan.nextInt();
    asString(xmas.Day, xmas.Month, xmas.Year);
    getYeardiff(Day, Month, Year);
    }
}
```

This is the method for a better overview.

```
public static int getYeardiff(int day, int month, int year) {
   System.out.println("Press <0>, if you want to know passed years between two dates. ");
   int difference = 0;
   int key = scan.nextInt();
   if(key == 0) {
       System.out.println("Enter a second date: ");
       Dates diffr = new Dates(Day, Month, Year);
       diffr.Day = scan.nextInt();
       diffr.Month = scan.nextInt();
       diffr.Year = scan. nextInt();
       if(diffr.Year <= Dates.Year) {
           difference = Dates.Year - diffr.Year;
           System.out.println(difference);
       }
   }
   return difference;
}
```

As is said, the output I get is always 0.
Here is the complete output:

```
Enter todays date!
12
12
2019
12.12.2019
Press <0>, if you want to know passed years between two dates. 
0
Enter a second date: 
12
12
1990
0
```

My question is, what do I have to change to get the correct output from my calculation method?

Comment: Use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)...

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking for values in the constructor of your class. Your constructor arguments are not assigned anywhere

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its against java standard to have fields using capital letters. Also your constructor for you `Dates` class isn't doing anything with the passed in arguments. Instead they are being assigned from scanner. This is also against convention. The scanner should be outside asking for input then you construct the class based off what the user input.

I modified your code as follows:

First your `Dates` class can be simplified to:

```
int day;
int month;
int year;

//Constructor
Dates(int day, int month, int year) {
  this.day = day;
  this.month = month;
  this.year = year;
}
```

Then I created a method to ask for the date input

```
public static Dates getDates() {
  int day = 0, month = 0, year = 0;

  System.out.print("Enter the day: ");
  day = scan.nextInt();

  while (day > 31 || day < 1) {
    System.out.println("Wrong day! repeat entry: ");
    day = scan.nextInt();
  }

  System.out.print("Enter the month: ");
  month = scan.nextInt();

  while(month > 12 || month < 1) {
    System.out.println("Wrong month! repeat entry: ");
    month = scan.nextInt();
  }

  System.out.print("Enter the year: ");
  year = scan.nextInt();
  while(year > 9999 || year < 1800 ) {
    System.out.println("Incorrect Year! repeat entry: ");
    year = scan.nextInt();
  }

  return new Dates(day, month, year);
}
```

Which then simplifies your `getYeardiff` and `asString` functions:

```
//Calculates Year difference
public static int getYeardiff(Dates other) {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Press <0>, if you want to know passed years between two dates. ");
  int difference = 0;
  int key = scan.nextInt();
  if(key == 0) {
    System.out.println("Enter a second date: ");

    Dates diffr = getDates();

    difference = Math.abs(diffr.year - other.year);
    System.out.println(difference);
  }
  return difference;
}

//Formats the date into a String.
public static String asString(Dates other) {
  String stringDay = "" + other.day;
  String stringMonth = "" +other.month;
  String stringYear = "" + other.year;
  String stringDate = stringDay + "." + stringMonth+ "." + stringYear;
  System.out.println(stringDate);
  return stringDate;
}
```

And finally your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Enter todays date!");
  Dates xmas = getDates();
  asString(xmas);
  getYeardiff(xmas);
  scan.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the whole code structure, you are using static variables and then you treat them as instance variables, try redesign your class properly having the DAY, MONTH, YEAR variables defined as normal variables not static coz static should only be used when you want to have some fixed value to be used on the class level not on the object level, and even you can separate your Dates class from the main class to make things easier and more clear for your self.

Answer (score 0):

`diffr.Year` and `Dates.Year` points to same value.

Pass the `xmas` object to `getYeardiff` and do `difference = Dates.Year - xmas.Year;`

For eg.
getYeardiff can be tweaked to

```java
    public static int getYeardiff(Dates today) {
        System.out.println("Press <0>, if you want to know passed years between two dates. ");
        int difference = 0;
        int key = scan.nextInt();
        if(key == 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter a second date: ");
            Dates diffr = new Dates(Day, Month, Year);
            diffr.Day = scan.nextInt();
            diffr.Month = scan.nextInt();
            diffr.Year = scan. nextInt();
            if(diffr.Year <= Dates.Year) {
                difference = differ.Year - today.Year;
                System.out.println(difference);
            }
        }
        return difference;
    }
```

main method can be tweaked to

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter todays date!");
        Dates xmas = new Dates(Day, Month ,Year);
        xmas.Day = scan.nextInt();
        xmas.Month = scan.nextInt();
        xmas.Year = scan.nextInt();
        asString(xmas.Day, xmas.Month, xmas.Year);
        getYeardiff(xmas);
    }
```

Comment: probably I'm doing something wrong, but when I try to pass the xmas object into the method I get the error:

xmas cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Unfortunately the output remains 0

Comment: Please see Anas Ablan's answer, you need to refactor your code.